# Fetch only public photos from user's Facebook profile with Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android app with the [Facebook SDK v2.6](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android). My purpose is to fetch the user's pictures, but only those shared with the **public** privacy setting. My test user currently has 2 public pictures and 1 shared only with friends. I am trying to get only those 2 pictures, but I get all 3.

This is the login button code:

```
LoginButton fbButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
fbButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_photos");
```

This is the code for the query:

```
Bundle fields = new Bundle();
fields.putString("fields", "images");
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(FBToken,
    "/me/photos/uploaded",
    fields, HttpMethod.GET);
GraphResponse response = request.executeAndWait();
```

I tried to follow the [documentation about the privacy node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/privacy/), but it is not very clear. It mentions fields `allow` and `value`, therefore I tried in these ways but it didn't work:

- `fields.putString("fields", "images,allow,value");` (no error but no additional output)
- `fields.putString("fields", "images,privacy");` (no error but no additional output)
- `fields.putString("fields", "images,privacy.allow,privacy.value");` (this does not provide a JSON output)

How can I ask only for public photos?

## Update with FQL

I have performed some tests using the Graph Explorer and I got the results I want with FQL:

```
select object_id, link, images
from photo
where object_id in (
    select object_id
    from privacy
    where (
        object_id in (
            select object_id from photo_tag where subject = me()
        )
        or object_id in (
            select object_id from photo where owner = me()
        )
    )
    and value = "EVERYONE"
)
```

However, I cannot use this in my app because the token I get is for version 2.6 and apparently I would need one for version 2.0. Can I somehow use this query with the latest SDK?

Comment: Have you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/ ? There is no privacy or allow or value field

Comment: @WizKid The [privacy node documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/privacy/) states: «The Privacy node is returned as part of a number of different types of nodes as a privacy field. **Examples include posts, photos and videos.**»

Comment: Then file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs because the two documentation pages are contradicting each other

Comment: @WizKid not necessarily. If a field is found in many places they might not need to repeat that information on all pages. This is a programming question: I am probably missing something to get the privacy field correctly and I am hoping to find someone who used the Facebook SDK to get this information before.

Comment: No it is wrong. It should be listed in the URL I posted if it exists. And you tried to get it and you didn't so obviously it doesn't exists

Comment: @WizKid You are assuming that my code must be correct which of course is quite a **strong** assumption. What is the most likely scenario? Facebook documenting an object that cannot be queried or me doing some error in the code?

Comment: No I'm assuming if there is a field called privacy then your code is correct. And then it is very likely that the documentation is wrong in your link and correct in my link. One of your and mine link is wrong. There is no way around that.

Comment: @WizKid I figured out a way to obtain the info with FQL (see the updated answer) however I can't get it to work in my app.

Comment: FQL will stop working in a few months so I have no idea why you would use that

Comment: @WizKid the graph API does not allow to check out privacy, it does not allow to filter results with a "where" clause... it's not that I *want* to use FQL, the point is that one is forced to use it if the "normal" API is feature-reduced. I would happily avoid FQL if a decent solution existed.

Comment: I know. I'm just telling you that you can't use FQL and even if you had an old app FQL would stop working 2 month from now. So using FQL is not a solution

Comment: @WizKid I see. :( Thank you for all your help so far.